# I ssh'd into my AWS Ubuntu server using PuTTY and the IP address is not accurate

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty, amazon-web-services

Here is what I typed in to PuTTY:

[ssh'ing using PuTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgoOi.png)

And `hostname -I` returns an ip address that is not what I typed as Host Name in PuTTY

[ip address of server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onBLz.png)

clearly I am doing something wrong. Can someone please explain to me what happened or is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Both IP addresses are accurate. AWS implements 1:1 NAT, so that the "Elastic IP" addresses could be moved from VM to VM by only reconfiguring the routing.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario1.html

(I think AWS also supports directly assigned public IP addresses – the kind that you would normally expect – but docs say that they are chosen dynamically, whereas Elastic IPs are static.)